# Android deeplinking default handler

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I am trying to use last default handling feature for deep linking site and app, introduced in Marshmallow release. 
I have done three steps, as described here (https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)

1. I have created intent handlers in my apk

   ```
           <data android:scheme="http"
               android:path="/cat.html"
               android:host="kino.tryremember.ru"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name=".DogActivity"
       android:exported="true"
       android:launchMode="singleTop">
       <intent-filter
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:autoVerify="true"
           tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

           <data android:scheme="http"
               android:path="/dog.html"
               android:host="kino.tryremember.ru"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. I have added assetslink json file on my test website (https://kino.tryremember.ru/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

As I noticed my app handle web site links and when I click in link on search result in google search in chrome for example it gives me chooser dialog, but as describe in docs (link above) there will be auto detection of default handler in fact my app would be default handler, cuz I have done all conditions.

But during installation I could see in logcat something like that

```
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:Verification result: checking for a statement with source a <
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:   a: "https://kino.tryremember.ru"
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: >
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: , relation delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls, and target b <
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:   a: "com.busylee.appindexingexample"
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:   b <
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:     a: "A7:93:BA:D8:DD:ED:F4:40:08:7B:C7:43:49:60:C3:4F:31:34:54:2F:58:AC:BE:D9:16:CB:C5:B9:2B:A3:B9:CA"
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:   >
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: >
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:  --> false.
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 D SingleHostAsyncVerifier: Remaining verification failures before we've exhausted all certs: 0
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 D StatementServiceResFut: setResult on host: a <
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 D StatementServiceResFut:   a: "https://kino.tryremember.ru"
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 D StatementServiceResFut: >
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19896 D StatementServiceResFut: : false
08-10 17:39:24.821  4755 19895 I IntentFilterIntentSvc: Verification 3 complete. Success:false. Failed hosts:kino.tryremember.ru.
```

I can not understand what's wrong. Have anyone any idea about what I have missed or are doing wrong?

Comment: Verify the applicationId of your app as well as the sha256 fingerprint of the keystore you're using

Answer (score 1):

I have found my fail. It is strict to add header `Content-Type application-json` for `.well-known/assetlinks.json` file, or you will face same error as me.